# Where do yesod binaries expect to find the config folder?

Tags: haskell, docker, yesod, docker-compose

#### Problem description

I'm creating a docker container to run haskell binary. The binary in question is a website built with yesod. When the container starts up it looks promising but then fails with:

```
config/client_session_key.aes: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

#### Steps to recreate

The Dockerfile for the binary is very basic. It looks like this:

```
FROM haskell:7.10.3
MAINTAINER Garry Cairns
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2015-09-05

RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "install", "libpq-dev"]
```

I use docker-compose to link it to the database. The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    env_file: ./database/env
  binary:
    build: ./binary
    command: /opt/server/api
    env_file: ./api/env
    links:
      - database
    tty: false
    volumes:
      - /etc/ssl/certs/:/etc/ssl/certs/
      - ./binary:/opt/server/
```

The binary's `volumes` line is particularly important as it loads the binary into the container along with its static and config directories. I've checked they're definitely there and they are, so the container file structure ends up looking like this:

```
/opt/server
    binary_file
    /static
        ...
    /config
        client_session_key.aes
        ...
```

Connecting to the database seems to be working as I see some lines like this in the logging

```
binary_1   | Migrating: ALTER TABLE "blog" ALTER COLUMN "title" TYPE varchar(50)
```

before I see the error message.

#### Question

I suspect I either need to move the config folder to an alternative location where the binary file is expecting to find it, or set an environment variable somewhere in the yesod app before building it. I've been unable to find either the expected location or the correct environment variable to set thus far. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: The error message makes it look like it looks for `config/client_session_key.aes` at a relative path to the current working directory (`CWD`). Is it something as simple as specifying `WORKDIR` in the `Dockerfile` or `working_dir` in the compose YAML to `/opt/server`?

Comment: @AndyShinn you, sir, win a prize. WORKDIR didn't do the trick, but `working_dir` did. Please add this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message makes it look like it looks for `config/client_session_key.aes` at a relative path to the current working directory (`CWD`). Is it something as simple as specifying `WORKDIR` in the `Dockerfile` or `working_dir` in the compose YAML to `/opt/server`?

Information on `WORKDIR` for setting default `CWD` at image build time would be at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir.

Information on setting Compose `working_dir` at runtime is at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cpu-shares-cpu-quota-cpuset-domainname-hostname-ipc-mac-address-mem-limit-memswap-limit-privileged-read-only-restart-stdin-open-tty-user-working-dir.